# CPU usage on dual socket motherboard

Tags: 22.04, cpu, cpu-load

Ubuntu's system monitor shows CPU usage for each core separately. I have a motherboard with two CPU sockets and want to know how much CPU on socket0 is loaded and how much CPU on socket1 is loaded. How can this be done?

The reason I want to know this is that when I run a specific program, the CPU on socket1 is much hotter than the CPU on socket2. First, I'm going to know if the two CPU's are loaded equally. Then, if that is the case, I can be sure that it is an issue with the cooling system (i.e. Fan, Heatsink, thermal paste, etc.).

Comment: The CPU cores in the graphs will be sequential. If your CPUs have 12 cores each (for example), then the first twelve numbers will be for Socket 0 while the latter 12 will be for Socket 1. I do not believe there is anything in the default utilities that will show details on a per-socket as an aggregate 

Answer (score 1):

You can try command like

```
sar -P 0-5,12-17 -u 1
```

where `-P` specifies the CPU core, `-u` specifies the display interval.

Just check the cpu usage in different sockets at the same time and you can check weather two CPUs are loaded equally.